# Как найти степень из операции bcpowmod?

Tags: php

```
$n = "35948145881546650497425055363061529726";
$mod = bcpowmod(1511, $x, $n);
```

Как из данного PHP-скрипта найти x?
$mod = "24358801334247076632661771105738015915";

Даже представить себе не могу такое огромное число 1511 в степени $x, а уж тем более как компьютер оперирует с ним. Помогите

Comment: Все значения верные?

Comment: да, все написано верно